# Implications of Asymptotic Lower Bound

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

Suppose we have the following statement
$$ \lim\inf_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{n^s} >0 $$
for any $0<s<\alpha$ for some given constant $\alpha>0$. I guess one way to write this statement is to use the Big-Omega symbol and write $a_n = \Omega(n^{\alpha-\epsilon})$ for any $0<\epsilon<\alpha$.

I'm wondering if such statement has any implication of the form $a_n = \Omega(n^{\alpha}\delta(n))$ for some function $\delta(n)$ satisfying some properties? For example, a more precise statement than $\delta(n)$ of order less than fractional-polynomial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't, no. If we restrict to the natural case where $\delta(n)$ is monotone:

- If $\delta(n) \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ but not as fast as a fractional power of $n$, then we can choose the counterexample $a_n = n^\alpha \delta(n)^2$;
- Otherwise we can choose say $a_n = n^\alpha/\log n$.

I guess the combined example $a_n = n^\alpha \min\{\delta(n)^2,1/\log n\}$ works for a general $\delta(n)$. (still assuming $\delta(n)$ is not $O(n^{-\varepsilon})$ for any $\varepsilon>0$)